# Incompatible pointer to character conversion

Tags: c

I'm writing a program to write card values into a 52 spot character multi-dimensional array. This program is one test array that I will write as a function into the main program later.
In the program I initialize a for loop counting by `0` through `51`. I use a `switch` statement modulated by `13` to assign the card value to the array spot. However, I receive the error pointer to integer conversion also how do I write values to the second spot in the array?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    char CardValue[52][6];
    int i;

    for (i=0;i<52;i++)
    {
        CardValue[i][6]=i;
CardValue[i];
        switch (i%13)
        {
            case '0': CardValue[i][6] = "ACE";
            break;

            case '1': CardValue[i][6] = "2";
            break;

            case '2': CardValue[i][6] = "3";
            break;

            case '3': CardValue[i][6] = "4";
            break;

            case '4': CardValue[i][6] = "5";
            break;

            case '5': CardValue[i][6] = "6";
            break;          

            case '6': CardValue[i][6] = "7";
            break;

            case '7': CardValue[i][6] = "8";
            break;

            case '8': CardValue[i][6] = "9";
            break;

            case '9': CardValue[i][6] = "10";
            break;

            case '10': CardValue[i][6] = "JACK";
            break;

            case '11': CardValue[i][6] = "QUEEN";
            break;

            case '12': CardValue[i][6] = "KING";

        }
```

Comment: `CardValue[i][6]` referes to only one `char` (type is `char`). `"ACE"` type is `char*`. More, `CardValue[i][6]` referes to a char outside of your array (you types `char CardValue[52][6];` so indexes are between [0-51][0-5]

Comment: What does line 11 do, if anything? `CardValue[i];` The previous line has a semi, so I don't think it should do anything.

Comment: Please before posting to SO show some research effort and consider googling the problem; people here is glad to help, but it is nice to put some effort in your problem before posting a question.
Also, be sure to properly indent your code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to doing a strcpy and not assigning string literals directly. Also, the array usage is wrong.

The code should be like below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    char CardValue[52][6];
    int i;

   /* Not clear what you are trying in the below 2 lines. But, it'll not work :-) */
    /*CardValue[i][6]=i;
    CardValue[i];*/    

    for (i=0;i<52;i++)
    {

        switch (i%13)
        {
            case '0': strcpy(CardValue[i],"ACE");
            break;

            case '1': strcpy(CardValue[i],"2");
            break;

          /** Do the same way for other case **/

        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should `#include <string.h>` and do something like this:

`case '0': strcpy(CardValue[i],"ACE");`

etc. Also note, that `CardValue[i];` has no effect at all. You should also remove `CardValue[i][6]=i;`, I don't really know what you meant by that, but it surely should not be there.